# How to hide a specific row of devexpress GridControl?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

in c# datagrid use this code:

```
dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Visible = false;
```

What is the equivalent in devexpress gridControl ?

Comment: please read this (it's from the dev express website) http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18363

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent is [`ColumnView.CustomRowFilter`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomRowFiltertopic) event. You can use this event to hide particular rows. Use [`RowFilterEventArgs.ListSourceRow`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseRowFilterEventArgs_ListSourceRowtopic.aspx) property to get the index of record in [`GridControl.DataSource`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_DataSourcetopic) and set [`RowFilterEventArgs.Visible`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseRowFilterEventArgs_Visibletopic.aspx) property to `false` and the [`RowFilterEventArgs.Handled`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseRowFilterEventArgs_Handledtopic.aspx) property to `true` to hide the row.
Here is example for hide row by `rowIndex` variable:

```
private void gridView1_CustomRowFilter(object sender, RowFilterEventArgs e)
{    
    if (e.ListSourceRow == rowIndex)
    {
        e.Visible = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```